# Using CSS sprites for an input of type image

Tags: html, asp.net, css, sharepoint-2013, html-input

I am creating a ImageButton that refers to a image, that contains several icons. I am trying to display the correct icon by positioning the background image, but that does not work. Here is how I create the `ImageButton`:

```
ImageButton closeButton = new ImageButton();
closeButton.CommandName = "CloseItem";
closeButton.ID = "BtnClose";
closeButton.Width = 16;
closeButton.Height = 16;
closeButton.ImageUrl = "/_layouts/15/1031/images/formatmap16x16.png?rev=23.gif";
closeButton.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Top, "-115");
closeButton.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Left, "-275");
closeButton.OnClientClick = btn.OnClientClick;
this.Controls.Add(closeButton);
```

Which results in the following HTML:

```
<input type="image" 
       name="ctl00$ctl40$g_8cd9fd5c_6191_46af_bf6a_ac27c5fb0e80$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl02$BtnClose" 
       id="ctl00_ctl40_g_8cd9fd5c_6191_46af_bf6a_ac27c5fb0e80_ctl00_toolBarTbl_RightRptControls_ctl02_BtnClose" 
       src="/_layouts/15/1031/images/formatmap16x16.png?rev=23.gif" 
       onclick="STSNavigate('http:\u002f\u002fespseis13\u002fsharechange\u002fdefault.aspx');return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl40$g_8cd9fd5c_6191_46af_bf6a_ac27c5fb0e80$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl02$BtnClose&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" 
       style="height:16px;width:16px;top: -115px;left: -275px">
```

The image I am displaying is this one:

[image]

**I can't swith the input type that easily, As it needs the property `CommandName = "CloseItem"`.**
Does anyone know, how I can move (and not scaling!) the image that is referenced by an `input` of type `image`?

Comment: I don't think you can use a sprite for `input[type = image]` can you?

Comment: man, that would be bad :(

Comment: Yeah: **"A graphical submit button. You must use the src attribute to define the source of the image and the alt attribute to define alternative text. You can use the height and width attributes to define the size of the image in pixels." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, it's possible to use a CSS sprite for an input of type of image; But as a background image.

You can assign a **transparent** image to `src` attribute and use [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) property to add/position a background image for the input element.

For instance:

```
<input type="image" src="path/to/transparent.png" alt="Cut" />
```

```css
input[type="image"] {
  width: 24px;
  height: 26px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/byld6.png) -60px 0 no-repeat;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/liwud/3/edit)**.